# Is there a Google Places API return field for restaurant dining options (ie. Dine-In, Takeout, Delivery)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api

During the pandemic around March, Google started allowing business owners to tag their restaurants with the dining option they offer in light of the pandemic.

[Here is an example of these tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCsbr.png)

I was wondering if the Places API (or any other Google API) has the ability to return these dining types. I've checked [the docs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults) for the Places API and it seems to only be capable of returning the business' `business_status` which only includes `OPERATIONAL, CLOSED_TEMPORARILY, CLOSED_PERMANENTLY` and not the fields I am looking for.

Would the only other way to obtain these tags be by web scraping a search result?

Answer (score 0):

I just spoke with Google support and they said no. There is also no plan in the future to add these data points to the JSON.

They gave me some workaround ideas but nothing realistic. Let me know if you find a workaround! I am trying to gather this data as well.